# Decoding parameters with inline assembly in Solidity

Tags: solidity, web3js, encoding

I Would like to know if there is  a solidity equivalent to this web3:

> web3.eth.abi.decodeParameter()

I'm currently looking at something like Seriality, but wondering if there was a supported native solidity implementation of the above. Including inline assembly.

My code looks something like: 
Web3 part:

```
var _data = await ABI.encode("120000000000000000000", user2, OCcontract1.address, "120000000000000000000", OCcontract2);
await swap(_data);
```

Solidity part:

```
Swap(_data){
     uint256 _amount;
     address _receiver;
     address _tokenLeadContract;
     uint256 _expectedAmount;
     address _expectedSC;

     (_amount, _receiver, _tokenLeadContract, _expectedAmount, _expectedSC) = decode(_data);

}
```

Comment: Can you please share your Solidity code, which requires such functionality?

Comment: Done, does this help at all?

Comment: Looks like you want to send 5 arguments of known types. So why do you need to encode these arguments on the client (web3) side to begin with, when you just send them "naturally".

Comment: Well we are going to be using `_checkOnOCTReceived()` which uses `onER721Received()` to determine whether we should call the function above, in order to comply with the stndard to the greatest extent possible we would like to use `bytes memory _data`, there is no real reason beyond this, but it would certainly look cleaner and be potentially more efficient.

Comment: And a lot less prone too accidentally sending incorrect input.

Comment: any thoughts, on how to encode decode then? encoding has to happen in web3 and decoding has to happen in solidity.
Alternatively I could develop a smart Contract to encode and decode the data in Solidity. Which is more expensive but more achievable I guess?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is available in Solidity as `abi.decode`. You can see the documentation here https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.5.3/units-and-global-variables.html?highlight=abi.decode#abi-encoding-and-decoding-functions

For example, your code would look something like

```
 (_amount, _receiver, _tokenLeadContract, _expectedAmount, _expectedSC) = abi.decode(_data, (uint256, address, address, uint256, address));
```

Comment: does this exist in pragma 5.2?

Comment: Yes, it should work in > 5.1

Comment: Works for <4 parameters at 5 it gives me an unknown compiler error `Unknown exception during compilation` it works when using the compiler for 5.3 perhaps a remix error? marking as correct regardless

Comment: Sounds like a compiler bug in 5.2, which got fixed in 5.3